# No resource identifier found for attribute 'fullBackupContent' in package 'android

Tags: android, backup

Why am I getting this error?

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'fullBackupContent' in
>   package 'android

Here's a snippet of my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/time_machine_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:name="com.friscosoftware.timelytext.TimelyTextApplicationBasic"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backupscheme" 
    >
```

The file backupscheme.xml resides in my res/xml folder. I'm trying to follow the instructions at [Configuring Auto Backup for Aps](http://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html)

Comment: What is your `compileSdkVersion` (or, if you are stuck on Eclipse, your build target from Project > Properties > Android)? Does `res/xml/backupscheme.xml` exist in your project?

Comment: Duh, still at 19.  Updating now.  Yes, res/xml/backupschme.xml exists. Thank you.

Comment: Installing SDK 23 fixed it.

Comment: My app uses a small database that I'd like to have backed up.  I'm assuming this won't happen automatically, without my coding for it using fullBackupContent as indicated above.  How do I modify the content of my backupscheme.xml to set the include path correctly? Also, is there a way I can go online to see what was backed up?

Comment: "How do I modify the content of my backupscheme.xml to set the include path correctly?" -- ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you show your `backupscheme.xml` file and how you are setting up the database (e.g., your `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor implementation). "Also, is there a way I can go online to see what was backed up?" -- not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Android SDK 23 fixed my issue.